# Increased size of compiled image assets in iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, asset-catalog

I recently added an iOS 8 Photos Extension to my existing (iOS 7-compatible) app. The extension shares some icons and other images with the main app. Since I can't use embedded frameworks yet to share those assets (not available in iOS 7) I have those assets added to both targets—the main app and the extension bundled within the app. So I expected an increase of the app's size by roughly factor two.

But here's the catch: the app is now roughly three times as large! I tried to figure why and found that the compiled assets in the extension bundle are more then twice the size (38.6 MB) compared to the assets in the main app (17.2 MB). This is strange because those came from the same asset catalog.

After some experimenting I found that it has to do with the iOS version. The extension target has iOS 8 as deployment target (obviously) and the main app still has iOS 7. When I change the deployment target of the main app to iOS 8 its compiled assets also become more then twice as large!

My guess is that for iOS 8 the asset compiler automatically generates @3x images for the iPhone 6 Plus, even though they are not provided explicitly. The problem is, I decided not to provide those on purpose to avoid an unnecessary increase of the app's size (how ironic...). The scaled-up version looked good enough for me. The app also works and looks as intended on the 6 Plus when built for iOS 7 (with small assets).

**TL;DR:** For iOS 8 the asset compiler produces much larger results then for iOS 7.

Is there a way to tell it not to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Try update Assets.xcassets compression setting from Default to Basic or GPU Best Quality or GPU Smallest Size.

The size of Assets.car will return to normal.

[image]